# How FileStream works in c#?

Tags: c#

I have this following piece of code.I an not fully understanding its implementation.
img stores the path of image as `c:\\desktop\my.jpg`

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(img, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
         byte[] bimage = new byte[fs.Length];

         fs.Read(bimage, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
```

In the first line the `filestream` is opening image located at path img to read.
The second line is (i guess) converting the file opened to byte.

What does fs.length represent?

Does image have length or is it the length of name of file(i guess not)?

What is the third line doing?

Please help me clearify!!

Comment: Your assumption about the second line is wrong, that is just creating the container that will hold a copy of the file in memory. The third line actually does the copying (I will leave it to someone else to write up a more detailed version answer). Also, [go read the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx), it will explain what each argument of the Read function represents.

Comment: And look up `FileStream.Length` to understand that part. By the way, this isn't good code - it's currently assuming that a single call to `Read` will read everything that's asked for. You shouldn't assume that with streams.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain if the second line is just creating a container then why not have  `byte[] bimage = new byte[];` instead of  `byte[] bimage = new byte[fs.Length];`

Comment: @Chelsea Because you have to tell it how large to make the container, `fs.Length` is the number of bytes in the file stream so you are saying *"Make a new array of bytes that is equal in size to the total number of bytes in the file stream"*. Arrays can not be resized after creation, you need to use a `List<byte>` to get the behavior you implied.

Answer (score 0):

fs is one of many C# I/O objects that presents file descriptor and some methods like Read in your example. Because Read method returns byte array, you should declare it first and set its length to file length (the second string, so fs.Length is file length in bytes). Then all you need is just read file content and store it in this array (third line). This could be done by one iteration (like in the example) or by reading blocks in a loop. When you done with reading, it is good approach to destroy fs object to prevent memory leakage.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remember what a buffer is. In computing, a buffer is a region of memory used to temporarily store data while it's being transferred from one place to another. This process enables compensation for a difference in speed or mode of operation between the producer and consumer of a data stream.

A "stream" is a buffer you open, read a chunk from, and then close. For files, the operating system locates the file, manages pointers, and locks the resource. You read a chunk, a byte range, into memory. The size of this chunk can vary, but physical memory limitations constrain it.

For instance, on low-memory systems like a Raspberry Pi B (512MB), large files may cause errors. Microsoft's `fs.Length` counts all bytes in the file, working faster for smaller files and slower for larger ones. This allows for calculating the optimal chunk size versus the maximum size.

However, buffer size should not be solely determined by file size; you must also consider maximum computer memory and concurrent memory-using processes. **Remember, ALWAYS CLOSE OR RELEASE LOCKED I/O RESOURCES. This is a frequent mistake of devs, even seniors, and it isn't good**. For example, reading a 10GB payment transaction log file on a Raspberry Pi with 512MB RAM + 2GB SD could be problematic.

Comment: This is a reply for @Leonardo Dutra but I don't have enough rep points.
Can you please tell me how the FileStream's buffer work? what is stored in that buffer and what size should I make it? I need to read the first couple of bytes (64 KB) from a larger file, then the second couple of 64 KB, etc. Is it ok if I make the buffer 64 KB? or it has to be the size of the file? And not only that, but how it actually work, because when you read files, you pass as a parameter your own byte array anyway so, I can't see what is stored in the buffer.
Edit: oh and if you have time to tell me what is the dea

Comment: @dCake for this explanation is better for you to look at language API reference. Depending on the language, there are different things to take in consideration and different streams and adapters which you should choose. If language API reference is too advanced to you, Google for "explaining file streams on Java", or another language. There will be more complete blog posts than a quick and limited SO comment.